# ошибка 500 при генерации sitemap

Tags: php, html, sitemap

здравствуйте, для самописного сайта хочу создать sitemap. но при генерировании через онлайн сервисы пишет ошибку 500. сайт работает без проблем, ssl сертификат установлен, robots.txt есть в корне. в файле .htaccess прописал код для ЧПУ. в коде использую роутер ссылки сайта: https://lptf.it/index.php?route=search так же поддерживаются https://lptf.it/search. Как создать sitemap или как исправить код чтоб в карте сайта были определены все внутренние адреса сайта.